# Displaying over 40k points on map

Tags: javascript, charts, gchart

I'm writing a code to display devices via GPS on map. I am using gcharts the `map` package because of amazing details and zooming ability with actual cities layout. However at the gcharts tutorial there's a note that map can only handle up to 400 points/entries. And after small test I confirmed it. Is there any possible solution to pass it by or is there any other option for map chart with as much detailization as gchart offers but without upper bound?

Comment: you have to show just needed points. like maps or games which just render surfaces in view scope.

Comment: I thought about it. However technically speaking I need to make all points one click away from user. Another option would be to set polygons since most points will be clustered in cities. So if I could make a polygon for each city and display points only for that city that could work. However the megapolis city may have more than 400 points, and that fact makes me really confused, since it's undefined scope and might be not presentable.

Comment: when user zoom out you can show just one point that has tooltip that show how many points is in that section